# "I am a student of / in / at / by the Example University"?

Tags: prepositions

What preposition is the right one to use in this example:

> I am a student **of** / **in** / **at** / **by** the Example University.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all: welcome!

> I am a student at Example University.

'in' or 'from' is more related to the location not the university. 'by' just sounds wrong to me.

*Note: I am neither a native speaker nor an expert - I am just trying to help.*